# Efficiently finding approximate fraction, with tolerance for fp rounding

Tags: python, performance, floating-point, rational-numbers

I needed to convert floating point numbers to int/int fractions. Python technically has this functionality, but has issues with rounding errors:

```
>>> (0.1+0.2).as_integer_ratio()
(1351079888211149, 4503599627370496)
```

This is what I wrote and I was wondering whether it could be further improved for performance?

```
def as_fraction(number: float, accuracy: float) -> (int, int):
    whole, x = divmod(number, 1)
    if not x:
        return int(whole), 1
    n = 1
    while True:
        d = int(n/x)
        if n/d-x < accuracy:
            return int(whole)*d+n, d
        d += 1
        if x-n/d < accuracy:
            return int(whole)*d+n, d
        n += 1
```

Comment: You do realize that `0.1+0.2` is actually `0.30000000000000004`, right? Which happens to be exactly `1351079888211149 / 4503599627370496`, so it's _your_ function which has issues with rounding errors. _Unless I misunderstood your question._ In either case, your function returns the wrong result for `0.1+0.2` with accuracy `0.0000000000000001`. With finer accuracy, it doesn't even return a result (in a reasonable time).

Comment: @kyrill yes, I know that `0.1+0.2 != 0.3`, the problem is that my program receives `0.30000000000000004` as input and needs to read it as `0.3` (rounding errors add up over time, causing problems), but fractions such as `1/7` prevent me from simply using `round(x)`

Comment: You're making some assumptions here. How exactly does your program know that the input is actually supposed to be `0.3`? But I agree that this function will hopefully in most cases reduce rounding errors, if the user of that function is aware of the implications.

Comment: @kyrill any valid input should be representable as n/d, where d has up to 5 digits. I checked and 1/d is calculated correctly for all d < 100000 given small enough `accuracy`. I believe that for other numerators it should also work correctly?

Comment: I can't say. I can just advise you to test the results of the built-in `as_integer_ratio` versus your function, and choose the one which better fits your needs – the one which gives better overall results _for your application_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the `float` to a [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(0.1 + 0.2)
Fraction(1351079888211149, 4503599627370496)
```

(this gives you the same ratio as [`float.as_integer_ratio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio)), and then use the [`limit_denominator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) method to return the closest fraction with a denominator of limited size:

```
>>> Fraction(0.1 + 0.2).limit_denominator(1000000)
Fraction(3, 10)
```

If you're interested in the maths behind the `limit_denominator` method, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266999/68063) on Stack Overflow.